# App Con webCam integrada

Tags: javascript, php

Buenos días, Si me pudieran dar una mano. mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo una app que integra la webcam y las fotografías tomadas con ella han de ser descargadas al equipo y estoy un poco perdido en este punto... ya tengo el script que toma la fotografía... es el siguiente:

```
function takepicture() {
   canvas.width = width;
   canvas.height = height;
   canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
   var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
   photo.setAttribute('src', data);
 }

 startbutton.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
     takepicture();
   ev.preventDefault();
 }, false);

})();
```

solo necesito poder descargarlo.... Y gracias de antemano..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según [éste Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/7PRNN/) el código sería algo así:

```
function downloadCanvas(link, canvasId, filename) {
    link.href = document.getElementById(canvasId).toDataURL();
    link.download = filename;
}

document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', function() {
    downloadCanvas(this, 'canvas', 'test.png');
}, false);
```

Está explicado en inglés en el mismo fiddle.